# Openerp Domain Filter Help on Tasks associated to Sales Team

Tags: odoo

I have been developing a lot of modules and implementing openerp for a wild. But I am stuck in a functional implementation.

I have installed the module crm_todo, it is for have tasks on crm, this module add "My Tasks" menu under Sales.

I need to create a new Menu with a Domain Filter called "Department Tasks" where will show all the task to all the members of an specific Sales Team. The task is assigned to User A; User A belongs to Sales Team A; Sales Team A has 2 more members. This new Menu have to list the task Assigned to User A to all the members of Sales Team A.

I was trying to do with field.function, but something is wrong. I am trying to apply the domain on act_window using the openerp Action Windows Menu and assigning it to the new Menu.

Comment: "something is wrong"  could you be please more specific what is gone wrong like any error message or more information about the error you are getting. Thank you.

Comment: can you show us what you r doing in form of small snippet so that we can identify your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying the login user sale team as domain parameter is not possible but there is another way in which we can achieve this. ie; in my view action i specify the domain as:

```
<field name="domain">[('user_id.default_section_id', 'in', user_sale_team())]</field>
```

where user_id is the responsible user of the task.
Now inherit read function of ir.actions.act_window and check if user_sale_team() is present in the domain of read result and replace this with the login user sale team id. This can be done as:

```
class ir_action_window(osv.osv):
_inherit = 'ir.actions.act_window'

def read(self, cr, uid, ids, fields=None, context=None, load='_classic_read'):
    user_pool = self.pool.get('res.users')
    obj_user = user_pool.browse(cr, uid, uid, context=context)
    res = super(ir_action_window, self).read(cr, uid, ids, fields=fields, context=context, load=load)
    if not isinstance(res, list):
        res = [res]
    sale_team_id = obj_user.default_section_id and obj_user.default_section_id.id or''
    for r in res:
        mystring = 'user_sale_team()'
        if mystring in (r.get('domain', '[]') or ''):
            r['domain'] = r['domain'].replace(mystring, str([sale_team_id]))
    if isinstance(ids, (int, long)):
        if res:
            return res[0]
        else:
            return False
    return res

ir_action_window()
```

This filters the result of the task to be displayed to each user based on his/her sale team.

Hope this helps.....

Comment: Perfect Answer, I apply two kinds of filters, one for related members and another for section_ids, The only thing you have to do is create "Function Key Names" and replace the value of it on the inheritance of ir_action_window. Thank You